Calling process inside Laravel always returns: command is not recognized on WIndows
Calling process inside Laravel always returns: command is not recognized on WIndows
I am trying to execute a bash file ,, and if i'm specified the full path to bash execute.sh,, then java is not found, monkeyC is not found, etc..
But if i run them manually in command prompt is working

You need to share more details, I have never saw that error, but I also have no idea what you are talking about, share the full error (as text), share what you are running literally, inside what, etc.
